# Android: Moving a View with onTouch has definite lag

Tags: android, graphics, ontouchlistener, lag, performance

I'm coming up the learning curve on Android, at the moment working on user interface details. One of the basic things I am trying is moving something around on the screen with my finger. Seems like a very fundamental thing to do.

I started with a RelativeLayout (RL), then created a 100x100 View that has a contrasting background color (intentionally simple, low graphics overhead) and add that View to the RL. Using View.setX and View.setY I can move the View around just fine.

Next, I added an onTouchListener to the View and used the resulting .getRawX and .getRawY values to move the View. It works - but there is a definite lag. I expected the View to stay right under my finger but it trails behind. It's very noticeable.

EDIT: Here's my onTouch code:

```
    public boolean  onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {

        boolean bExitValue = true;
        int     iAction;

        iAction = event.getActionMasked();

        if (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE == iAction) {
            v.setX(event.getRawX());
            v.setY(event.getRawY());
        }

        else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN != iAction) {
            bExitValue = false;
        }

        return(bExitValue);

}
```

I've tightened up the onTouch method as much as possible to keep it efficient - I'm only using primitives, no objects are being created, etc. - but that didn't help. Further things I've tried:

- Reducing the size of the View from 100x100 to 50x50, thus dropping the number of pixels that must be redrawn by 75%. No improvement.
- Overrode View.onTouchEvent instead of registering an onTouchListener. No improvement.
- Added android:hardwareAccelerated="true" to the manifest. No improvement.
- It seems counterintuitive, but I tried inserting a Thread.sleep() in the MotionEvent handler, based on various comments I found online that suggested doing so. No improvement, but definitely got the predictable slowdown as the sleep value increased!
- Used MotionEvent.getx and .getY instead of the "raw" versions. Got interleaved pairs of coordinates that appeared to be absolute and relative, making the View jumpy, so I abandoned that for now but will research when this current question is resolved.

I'm running my code on a new Google Nexus 7, so I don't think the hardware is starving for throughput.

Moving an object on the screen with your finger is really fundamental. I've got to be missing something, because no one would ship commercial code with the slow reaction time I'm seeing.

I've scanned here, and everything Google can find, but no solutions yet. Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Posting your code would be nice so we could see if there are some things which we could help you improve. :)

Comment: Posted, see above. Sorry for the omission. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have an issue with your code, I have implemented simple Drag and have the same symptoms as you, this is a device related issue, each device has it's own lag when it calls your on touch. If you enable show touch (ICS and above) on your device you will see that it lags a little comparing to real input. And you are not the only one experiencing this issue. There are a lot of discussions about this.

EDIT: If you are really bothered about this, here is a suggestion, this is only noticeable on high speed input, try measuring the speed of input and then anticipate where would be the next point, but this brings issues with sudden changes of direction, and this concept needs a lot of thinking through.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I wouldn't say it's "only noticeable on high speed input", though. I can see/feel it just moving my finger around on the screen. I could understand if this were a low-end <$100 tablet, but expected that Google's signature tablet would have the horsepower and hardware to handle common things like moving objects around by touch. A LOT of games are based on that interface... how do they deliver a decent user experience?

Comment: I did enable Show Touch and yes, the effect exists there too. The Nexus 7 gets high marks for its graphics performance, so this must be on the input side of things as you suggested... the device is slow to sense, or report, touches as opposed to being slow on graphics rendering. Amazing that Google would tolerate that on their flagship tablet. I'm marking your response as the accepted answer; thank you very much for confirming my findings!